# angular material: make a flex item inside a column grow with content (IE11 issue)

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, flexbox, angular-material

I'm trying out angular material and I wanted to achieve a column design which has a header, a middle section and a footer. The header and the footer should just have a limited height, based on the content. The middle section should take up all the remaining space or expand further with more content.

So I tried it the following simple way:

```
<body layout="column" layout-align="start center">
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="middle" flex="noshrink"></div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</body>
```

DEMO: [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/coceboweva/1/edit)

This works very nicely in chrome, firefox and safari. However in IE11, the middle section doesn't grow larger and the content just overflows.

So how can I make this right? Is a flex layout maybe not the right approach and it is not meant to work like that or are there issues with IE11?

Comment: internet explorer is, unfortunately, not good with flexbox. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex here you can see that is considered as "partial support" with many issues and bugs

Comment: also one of the most difficult things in frontend design is working with vertical alignment and fillings. That is extremely hard to do in IE

Comment: @Gianmarco Ok, I see. Do you know if there workarounds for this particular issue?

Comment: unfortunately the only solution is not to use flexbox at all. Or drop (finally!) support for IE

Comment: @basilikum You want a fixed header and footer or just a header ?